# Is $X^4+X^3+X+1$ reducible?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

The polynomial $X^4+X^3+X+1$ over $\mathbb{k}[x]$ does not seem to be reducible, but I cannot find a way to prove it. Eisenstein criteria doesn't apply here, I think.

I tried some alternative form, thinking something like $(x^2+1)^2+x^3+1-2x^2$ may make it clear but it doesn't.

Comment: Isn't this $\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$?

Comment: @Mark: it's missing the $X^2$.

Comment: $(x^4+x^3)+(x+1)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I made the same mistake and now have an embarrassing deleted answer > <

Comment: It's reducible,and the first thing that you simply have to do is to plug in rational roots. It's $(x+1)^2(x^2-x+1)$.

Comment: what is the field $\mathbb{K}$ you are considering ?

Comment: $x^4+x^3+x+1=(x+1)(x^3+1)$ works over any field.

Comment: @HectorBlandin A generic field. The answer should work over any field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because: $\ x^{4}+x^{3}+x+1=x^{3}(x+1)+(x+1)=(x+1)(x^{3}+1)$.